# My wallet refuses to display balance after updating firebase

Tags: flutter, dart

After updating this line in Future builder

```
Container(
  child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(RitechApp.sharedPreferences
        .getString(RitechApp.userUID))
        .get(),
    builder: (c, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor:
            new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(
                kPrimaryColor),
          ),
        );
      else {
        return Text(
          "KES" +
              snapshot..data.data["Wallet"]
                  .toString() ??
              0.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: "Muli",
              color: Colors.white),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

This following firebase database update and as well as observing null safety rules, I'm unable to retrieve wallet balance or update with each transaction. This is the code:

```
Container(
  child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
    future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("users")
        .doc(RitechApp.sharedPreferences
            .getString(RitechApp.userUID))
        .get(),
    builder: (c, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData)
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
            valueColor:
                new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(kPrimaryColor),
          ),
        );
      else {
        return Text(
          "KES" + snapshot.data!["Wallet"].toString() ??
              0.toString(),
          style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 25,
              fontFamily: "Muli",
              color: Colors.white),
        );
      }
    },
  ),
),
```

I'm unable to retrieve wallet balance or update with each transaction. This is the code.

Comment: are you using statefullWidget?

Comment: are getting CircularProgressIndicator visible for always?

Comment: yes my home widget extends a statefulwidget and yes the circularprogressindicator visible always

Answer (score 0):

Create a state variable for future like

```dart
  late final myFuture = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("users")
      .doc(RitechApp.sharedPreferences.getString(RitechApp.userUID))
      .get();
```

and use FutureBuiler like this, you will get error message if something fails

```dart
child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot?>(
  future: myFuture,
  builder: (c, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
     // 
      return Text(
        // "KES ${snapshot.data?["Wallet"] ?? 0} ",
         "KES ${snapshot.data?.get("Wallet") ?? 0}",
        style: TextStyle(
            fontSize: 25, fontFamily: "Muli", color: Colors.white),
      );
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Text(" ${snapshot.error}");
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.red),
        ),
      );
    }
  },
),
```

Comment: I get this error - The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'. It cocmes from data["Wallet"]

Comment: try `snapshot.data?["Wallet"] ?? 0`

Comment: and `snapshot.data?.get("Wallet") ?? 0`

Comment: same result no data being displayed

Comment: Do you see any error message or see `KES ....`

Comment: KES without the value being passed

Comment: It depends on your data, try to print `snapshot.data` and share the result

Comment: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot

Comment: try `snapshot.data?.get("Wallet")` and make sure if you have `Wallet` key on database, else you will receive 0

Comment: Still noting do you think this could be the reason

Comment: can the error be because im using test mode of the payment method im integrating or?

Comment: I have checked the entire code including my wallet firebase read code is all good

Comment: test mode is open for read and write<date, check the rules section